# SharePoint online certifcation path?

Tags: sharepoint-online

Alright so I am asking broad question here and please correct me if I am not posting this in the right exchange.

I have worked and been developing on SharePoint 2013/16 on prem. for quite a few years now and I am trying to transition my career to Office 365. I have a few questions.

1) Are there any certification paths I should follow for SharePoint online? 
2) Are there any boot camps/course out there that would help prepare a company for a transition from 2013/2016 to SharePoint online? 
3) What are some major headache’s during a transition from on-prem to online.

Answer (score 0):

You could find all microsoft certifications here: https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/learning/browse-all-certifications.aspx

For more details for sharepoint certification, please refer to this article:https://www.scnsoft.com/blog/sharepoint-certifications

Microsoft 365 certification exam and traning:https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/learning/microsoft-365-exams.aspx

I think the biggest difference between SharePoitn 2013/2016 and SharePoint online is SharePoint online using modern experience. Please read this article to know about modern experience in SP online: https://support.office.com/en-us/article/sharepoint-classic-and-modern-experiences-5725c103-505d-4a6e-9350-300d3ec7d73f